# Finding class extended Class and implement Interface

Tags: java, class

I try to use google reflections to finding class which extended abstract class like **A** and implement interface **I**. I looked in API but with no result. 
My code so far:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.my.company");
Set<Class<? extends A>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(A.class);
        subTypes.forEach(clazz->{
            System.out.println(clazz.getSimpleName());
        });
```

Can any one suggest how I can add next conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose (did not test), this will filter out the right interfaces in the forEach loop:

```
for(Class face : clazz.getInterfaces())  {
    if( face.isAssignableFrom(I))  ... do sth ...;
}
```

`I` is the `I.class` of the interface you are looking for.